# 3D Rendering in C# WPF and Anti-Aliasing

Tags: c#, wpf, antialiasing

Hello sorry for my bad English!

I created lines in a `Viewport3D`. Those lines are represented by `parallelipipeds`.

**Problem**: When I create multiple lines with the same caracteristics (width/height/depht), some are wider than the others.

**Solution**: I use `Anti-Aliasing` by setting the attached property of the

```
viewport3D => RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(myViewport, EdgeMode.Unspecified);
```

The lines are now exactly the same. To find out the above solution, first I :

- Checked if the lines had really the same caracteristics (in case I made  mistakes in my programmation).

  Result: The lines had exactly the same caracteristics (except they have differents coordinates).
- Checked if it was because I represent one line with one `parallelipiped`. I supposed that if the parallelipiped was slightly rotated, then the width of the line projected could change.

  So: I change `parallelipiped` for cylinder => the projection of a cylinder, regardless to the rotation of this one, always have the same width. But even with cylinders, some lines were wider than the others.

I realised that it wasn't my programmation the problem, but the rendering. And I found that I could change the rendering with the attached property `EdgeMode`.

When I set the `EdgeMode` to `Unspecified` (= `Anti-Aliasing` `enabled`) then all lines were perfectly rendered, they all have the same `width`. But if I set back `EdgeMode` to `Aliased` (= `Anti-Aliasing` `disabled`) then the problem was there.

My question is: Why do I have this problem? Can I do something else instead of changing the `EdgeMode`?

Thank you for any help.